# Less throughput with small packets

Tags: linux, networking

I have a question why the throughput of my machine is very bad with a SMALL sized packet (i.e 64bytes) when compared with the packet sized 1500bytes?

I am having a GIGABIT NIC card and able to transmit at 80MB/s for 1500bytes sized packets but in the case 64bytes sized packet I can hardly make out around 25MB/s.

I know that in the case of 1500byte packets I need to send around 80k PPS to reach line rate and for 64bytes its around 1.4 million PPS.

But why there is a huge variation in throughput for small sized packets ??

**EDIT:** I am using memory mapping to transmit the packets from user-space to kernel-space in linux and then directly writing into the network driver to transmit. And I see my CPU utilization is very less and same when compared between 64bytes and 1500bytes packets.

Comment: Imagine trying to empty a full bathtub with a thimble vs a bucket...

Comment: @codingfreak i have an 10Gbps network and want to achieve line rate i am only able to achieve line rate by packet size 7000 to 9000 but i want to achieve the line rate by 1500 packet size.What should i do please suggest

Answer (score 3):

> But why there is a huge variation in throughput for small sized
>   packets ??

CPU strain. Independent of its size, each packet that gets out passes through a lot of processing before reaching the interface. Put another way, the "costs" of transmitting a small packet and a large packet are comparable.

If you're interested in this you might want to look into "GSO" and "UFO" in the Linux kernel - it was developed specifically for this.

Comment: i have an 10Gbps network and want to achieve line rate i am only able to achieve line rate by packet size 7000 to 9000 but i want to achieve the line rate by 1500 packet size.What should i do please suggest

Comment: @user2087340 Are you using TCP or UDP ?

Answer (score 1):

It takes time to send packet headers.  It takes time to setup DMA buffers, process packet headers, etc.  All that extra work reduces the amount of actual payload that can be sent.

Comment: i have an 10Gbps network and want to achieve line rate i am only able to achieve line rate by packet size 7000 to 9000 but i want to achieve the line rate by 1500 packet size.What should i do please suggest

Comment: @user2087340: Physics doesn't care what you want.  You can try using a faster processor, which will waste less time on the setup and processing steps I mentioned, but there's nothing you can do about the packet header overhead except use fewer (larger) packets.

Comment: Sir i am already using the sandy bridge and is there no way to achieve the line rate at 1500 packet size and sir can you please send your mail id on cloverobert@gmail.com,i have few other queries too

Answer (score 0):

Think about this: each packet has its header contains the size of payload(data) and some general data. lets say the header are 16 bytes.

If you send 1000 packets of 64 bytes you send `1000 * (64 + 16) = 64000 + 16000 bytes`.

If you send it in one shot it is only `64000+16 bytes`.

Comment: I agree. To transmit the same amount of data using 64bytes packets I need to trigger send operation 1000 times while in other case it would be less. But in both cases my CPU utilization is almost the same. let us say in case of 1500bytes I need to trigger 80k times when compared to 1.4million times in case of 64bytes. But still even with 64bytes I should be able to reach throuhput of min of 60MB/s right ?

Comment: No, the limiting factor is how many packets can be sent per second.  If you send fewer bytes per packet, you'll be able to send fewer bytes per second.

Comment: @IvoC i have an 10Gbps network and want to achieve line rate i am only able to achieve line rate by packet size 7000 to 9000 but i want to achieve the line rate by 1500 packet size.What should i do please suggest

Comment: @user2087340 That's probably not achievable.  You'd need to make sure that your network components (OS, network driver, network interface card, switches, routers) are able to sustain 10Gbps line rate with 1500 packet size.  Most of-the-shelf network components will not be able to, and you'll need to use bigger packet sizes to achieve 10Gbps sustained throughput.

Comment: @IvoC Sir i have few other things to ask can you please send your mail id on cloverobert@gmail.com

Comment: @user2087340 do you pay by cash or credit card? ask here and someone will help you :)